# Ratios. In how much time could they complete the work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 20 students can clean 5 classrooms in 4 hours, so in how many hours can 40 students clean 40 classrooms?

Comment: since you don't want to proide any of your efforts, answer: 16

Comment: Your question is more likely to get answered if you show the community what you have tried already... or if you explain more precisely what you do not understand :)

Comment: If one car can drive from New York to Boston in 5 hours, how long would it take 6 cars?

Answer (score 1):

$20$ students can clean $5$ classrooms in $4$ hours,

$40$ students can clean $5$ classrooms in $4\cdot\dfrac{20}{40}$ hours  (as time is inversely proportional to the man power)

$40$ students can clean $40$ classrooms in $4\cdot\dfrac{20}{40}\cdot\dfrac{40}5$ hours  (as the quantity of task is directly proportional to the time)